# Was Silvio Berlusconi working together with the Italian mafia?

Tags: politics, italy, organized-crime

[Berlusconi implicated in deal with godfathers](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2002/dec/05/italy.philipwillan) - *The guardian*

> Silvio Berlusconi, the Italian prime minister, was in personal contact
>   with some of the mafia's most senior bosses, a major mafia turncoat
>   has told investigators in a deposition revealed yesterday. Antonino
>   Giuffre, a powerful boss who began collaborating with magistrates in
>   the summer, said the mafia decided to back Mr Berlusconi's Forza
>   Italia party from its foundation in 1993, in exchange for help in
>   resolving the mafia's judicial problems.

[Explaining the rise of Forza Italia](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2003/jan/12/italy.philipwillan)  - *The guardian*

> Courtroom testimony of Cosa Nostra's No. 2 explains sudden demise of
>   Christian Democrats and mysterious rise to power of Forza Italia

Is there any truth to this? Was Berlusconi aiding the mafia, and in return getting aid from them, or was he even their puppet? Is this a 'trend' and have other prime ministers of Italy also been linked to the mafia?

Comment: According to the article the mafia was helping Berlusconi who promised to repeal certain laws once he got to power. When he got to power he didn't repeal those laws. On the other hand Berlusconi didn't push much to persecute the Mafia either.

Comment: Found a link about modern mafia. http://www.globalpost.com/dispatch/italy/100719/white-collar-mafia-ndrangheta